# Efficiently retrieve a PHP object from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I have the following PHP classes:

**User.php**

```
<?php

class User {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

?>
```

**Forummessage.php**

```
<?php

class Forummessage {

    public $id;
    public $user_id; // message coming from this user
    public $message;
    public $datetime;

    // Additionally, an object should be able to get the user instances
    public $user; // should be instance of User
}

?>
```

Of course the class properties are usually private and accessed with public setters/getters. In order to keep this example as easy as possible, I made everything public.

---

Furthermore, assume the following MySQL tables.

**user**

```
id   name
------------
1    tester
2    anyuser
...
```

**forummessage**

```
id   user_id   message    datetime
---------------------------------------------
1    1         hello...   2014-04-04 12:00:00
2    2         yoyo...    2014-04-04 12:00:10
...
```

---

What is the fastest and most performant way to get an array of Chatmessage with all properties given?

Right now, I have a PDO wrapper class with this method:

```
/**
 * Performs a query to the database and returns the desired type
 * @param string $statement the pdo query
 * @param array $params the params
 * @param string $returntype optional param (default: 'bool'), should be either 'bool', 'array' or a valid class name
 * @return bool|array returns either a bool depending on the success of the query or an array with the resulting data
 */
function query($statement, $params = array(), $returntype = 'bool');
```

In case I pass a valid class name as `$returntype`, then this method uses `$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $returntype);` in order to return an array of class instances.

That is how I would do it:

```
// Automatically generates an array of Forummessage
$arrayOfForummessage = $wrapper->query('
    SELECT
        forummessage.id AS id, // NOTE: I MAKE SURE THE PROPERTIES MATCH TO THE PHP CLASS
        user_id AS user_id,
        message
        datetime,
        name AS user_name // NOTE: NOT USED YET
    FROM user, forummessage
    WHERE user.id = forummessage.user_id
', array(), 'Forummessage');
```

This works well, but as you will understand the property `user` is still `NULL`. How would you make sure that the user property is given? As you can see, the data is in the query.

Of course I could just make a for-loop into the `Forummessage` constructor and look for the right properties in order to fill create an instance of `User` and assign it to the `Forummessage` class property. The problem is that this is really slow when having many properties and many objects. If you have suggestions, I am curious to read more about them.

Comment: Check out how to use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) - that will help you out.

Comment: You will have to abandon `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` and do it manually instead. There are N ways to do this depending on requirements, but a simple one would be: name dependent columns according to some convention, e.g. with the `user_` prefix you have here. Then your code can split on `_`, gather all the `user_` columns, check that `new Forummessage` has a property `$user` which is a `User` instance and do the right thing. Too much for a single question.

Comment: @cale_b this is not a MySQL problem, but a PHP problem, I am already joining the tables. Jon, I thought about passing the values to the constructor, but isn't this horribly slow when I manually loop through it?